# Como usar SQL min() com float?

Tags: sql, jsp

Tenho o seguinte tabela de banco de dados:

```
 *Table structure for table `resultados` */
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `resultados`;

    CREATE TABLE `resultados` (

      `cpf` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
      `nome` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `codcurso` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nota` float DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`cpf`)

);

/*Data for the table `resultados` */

insert  into `resultados`(`cpf`,`nome`,`codcurso`,`nota`) values 
('123.456.789-01','Alexandre Mie Lopes Mesa',78,4.21),
('123.876.332-72','Maria Ximenes Rosa',1,9.16),
('222.333.444-55','Livia Fernandes Linderberg',43,9.87),
('232.234.789-77','Karol Linderberg',43,8.92),
('289-890-912-76','Pedro Solano Susp',16,4.21),
('345.678.900-37','Amilton Pedro da Silva',78,9.98),
('432.654.987-21','Julio Martinez Silva',21,7.34),
('454.098.123-45','Luiz Henrique de Souza',1,7.35),
('765.123.098-22','Juliana Lopes Alves',22,5.67),
('903.201.871-23','Luiz Peres Lopes',16,8.77),
('987.654.321-10','Ana Alves de Souza',78,9.12);
```

E quero selecionar o valor minimo, quando uso apenas:

```
SELECT min(nota) AS menor FROM resultados
```

Obtenho o resultado (4.21), porém se quero criar uma tabela, com os alunos com menor nota eu não consigo tal tabela

```
SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE nota = 4.21
```

Tentei também salvar este valor como float e passar como var mas não foi possível, só consegui fazer com o seguinte codigo:

```
SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE nota like '" + menorR + "'"
```

onde menorR = 4.21

Logo quero entender o motivo pelo qual o where nota = (número float) não funcionou

Comment: Em vez de usar float porque não usas decimal?  `\`nota\` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL`, por exemplo

Comment: SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE nota = (SELECT min(nota) AS menor FROM resultados)   o que retorna ?

Comment: @JorgeB. Por curiosidade: Qual a diferença de `Float` e `Decimal`?

Comment: @Andrey - Decimal armazena o valor exato..ex: 4.21... Com float/double (ponto flutuante), ele poderia armazenar algo como 4,2099999... i.e.. futuramente, vc pode vir a ter alguns problemas com arredondamentos.

Comment: @Andrey A diferença é precisão dos números que são guardados. Com `Float` não te garante a precisão dos números. Com `Decimal` garante-te a precisão mas perdes casas decimais. [Fonte SOEN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5150314/1817673)

Answer (score 1):

Isso aqui funciona:

```
SELECT *
FROM resultados
WHERE nota = ( SELECT min(nota) AS menor
               FROM resultados )
```

Veja no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ebfe/4 (às vezes fica fora do ar por um tempo `=(` )

O problema é de precisão: Ele não vai achar `4.210000038147` se você fizer só `WHERE nota = 4.21`.

---

Como bem disse o @JorgeB. nos comentários da pergunta, o ideal seria usar `DECIMAL` em vez de `FLOAT`, porque o `DECIMAL` você define a precisão. Por exemplo: três casa antes da vírgula e duas casas depois da vírgula:

```
CREATE TABLE `resultados` (
  `cpf` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codcurso` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nota` decimal(3, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cpf`)
);
```

Em `decimal(3, 2)`, o primeiro número são as casas antes da vírgula, e o segundo as casas depois da vírgula.

Feito isso a versão abaixo deve funcionar (créditos: @JorgeB.):

```
SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE nota = 4.21
```

Comment: +1 muito boa resposta. Falta acrescentar que se for com `decimal` já pode usar a versão `SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE nota = 4.21`.

Comment: @JorgeB. Atualizado =)

Comment: Na verdade no `float` também é possível selecionar a presição do mesmo, o que muda entre um e o outro é que o `float` utiliza de uma representação binária do número, enquanto o `Decimal` utiliza dos números em uma notação decimal. É por isso que o `float` não consegue representar exatamente os números a ele atribuídos.